# Use 2 databases to alternate loading vs reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

Because of an extremely long loading process, I have a need to switch between 2 identical sql databases for reporting purposes.  This will allow one to be used for reporting during business hrs while the other is reloaded.

Is there a way to dynamically assign the connection for the SSRS reports and SSIS packages to the database that is most current?

Exampe:

Mart1, 
Mart2

Point SSRS at Mart1 for reporting while Mart2 is being loaded.  The next day, Point SSRS at Mart2 while Mart1 is being loaded.

Additionally, the SSIS packages will have to make the same switch.

Is there an elegant solution to accommodate this?

Comment: possible in ssis using expression in connection manager. but I doubt we ca do it in SSRS.

Comment: What version of SQL Server (SSRS) you are using? Are you using Shared DataSet and DataSource in your reportserver?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar where we are switching between three servers in SSRS.

I am using an **Environment** parameter to choose which environment with a default value.

I have a datasource with an Embedded connection with an expression of:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Environment.Value = "PRD", "Data Source = KXTSQLPRD01\PRDMAIN; Initial Catalog = PlanData", 
    IIF(Parameters!Environment.Value = "UAT", "Data Source = KXTSQLUAT01\UATMAIN; Initial Catalog = PlanData", 
    "Data Source = KXTSQLTST01\TSTMAIN;Initial Catalog = PlanData_Training"))
& ";User ID=username;Password=password1"
```

Change the Credentials to **Do not use credentials**.

You can use the time from **NOW** to determine which should be your default.